# Php date add one day from database information

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp

I have this line of code:

```
<?= date('F dS, Y',$user_info['date_of_birth']) ?>
```

It gets the unix birtday date per user and converts it in a normal date.
The only problem is that it will show one day earlier.
For example, the unix date in the database is 11th may 1990.
In the view it will output, 10th may 1990.
Do you know how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd look at timezone issues.

Comment: That's maybe the problem. Do you know how I can just add + one day to the line of code above?

Comment: Don't do that. Fix the issue so your timezones match up.

Comment: Oke but just to know? Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explicitly answer your question, you can do the following:

```
<?=date('F dS, Y',($user_info['date_of_birth'] + 86400))?>
```

Where 86400 is the number of seconds in a day.

---

However, as others suggested, you can and should sync up the database and Php to UTC/GMT time.

For Php timezone, do the following at top of your scripts:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

For SQL, that depends on the database you're using (I don't believe you specified the database you're using).

Comment: Thank that works perfect. And I will look at the timezones now!

Answer (score 0):

Check into synchronizing your MySQL and PHP timezones.  Check out this similar question/answer:

[Set timezone in PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428563/set-timezone-in-php-and-mysql)

Comment: Thanks! for the info:) But do you know how to add +1 day in the line of code above?

Comment: Try something like this: date('F dS, Y', strtotime($user_info['date_of_birth'] . ' +1 day')) .

Comment: I do agree with chris, you should probably just take the steps to align timezones so you don't run into similar issues elsewhere in the application.

Comment: When I tried your code I got an output of   December 31st, 1969 and it suppose to be 11th may 1993

Answer (score 0):

It is probably time on you server is wrong. Is you have accesse to it shell you can check it by `date` command:

```
[centos@application ~]$ date
Tue Jul  5 04:17:00 UTC 2016
```

if not then you probably will have to do like this :

```
define('TIMEZONE_OFFSET', 86400);
<?=date('F dS, Y',($user_info['date_of_birth'] + TIMEZONE_OFFSET))?>
```

Again if you have access to mysql console check its timezone settings.

[set-timezone-in-php-and-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428563/set-timezone-in-php-and-mysql)

Also set manually php defaulte timezone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```