# php and mysql code works on localhost but there is issue with online server

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I am working on web app for treasure hunt all connection to the online server is correct and the application is working fine and save and get the data from / to online mysql database.

on my application I register a session for (**start time**) and session for (**end time**) where the (**end time**) means that the user has finished the game.

I am getting the winner number from this (**end time**) and organize the winners based on there (**end time**)

the problem is that on **localhost** (using XAMPP) I get the winner number correctly. while if I upload my work to my hosting (**Linux with CPanel**) I always get the winner as 0 (even if it wasn't the first)

**This is the result that I get online**

[image: this is the result that I get online]

**while if I am on localhost I get the winner number correctly**

[image: localhost I get the winner number correctly]

**this is the code to get the winner:**

```
function getWinner($uid, $set){

    $db = new Db();
    $winner = 0;
    $query = "SELECT endtime FROM eid_race WHERE id = '$uid' AND endtime IS NOT NULL";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    if(sizeof($result) == 0){
        $updateEndtime = "UPDATE eid_race SET endtime = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE id = '$uid'";
        $db->execute($updateEndtime);
    }
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM eid_race WHERE id <> '$uid' AND endtime IS NOT NULL AND endtime < (SELECT endtime FROM eid_race WHERE id = '$uid') AND questionset = '$set'";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    echo '  result:  ' . $result[0][0];
    if(sizeof($result) == 1){
        $winner = $result[0][0];
        echo '  winner:  '.$winner;
    }

    echo '  winner after:  '.$winner;


    return $winner+1;

}
```

when I test the query directly on phpmyadmin I get correct result but the php result still 0

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM eid_race WHERE id <> '577dd5759fa67' AND endtime IS NOT NULL AND endtime < (SELECT endtime FROM eid_race WHERE id = '577dd5759fa67') AND questionset = 'A'
```

[image]

Comment: Put a test file with phpinfo() on server and compare the PHP/Mysql versions.

Comment: @SumanSingh is right and since you are dealing with `datetime` and `timestamp` in `mysql` then you should check the server `timezone` and `date time settings`.

Comment: @SumanSingh **localhost:** PHP Version 5.6.15 , mysql Client API version mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev , **Online Server:** PHP Version 5.3.29,  mysql Client API version 5.6.30  --

Comment: @AvishekChat how can I prevent the changes between online timezone and localhost. **localhost timezone:** Europe/Berlin , **Online Server Timezone: ** UTC

Comment: Run "SELECT COUNT(id)...." query directly into phpmyadmin..

Comment: @SumanSingh I tested the code and it returns correct result on phpmyadmin (check my post update)

Comment: Please echo the query and run into directly on live server phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `timezone` of `mysql` on `my.ini` file in **windows** and `my.cnf` file in **linux** and **mac** system.
But I think the best solution is to change the timezone from query using

```
 set time_zone = '+2:00';   --Timezone:Europe/Berlin
```

and check the `current datetime` using `select now();`

Comment: my localhost time_zone is  '+2:00' (Europe/Berlin), Online is UTC

Comment: checking SELECT now() *localhost: * 2016-07-07 08:43:12, **Online: ** 2016-07-07 13:43:49

Comment: Ok, then run the query `set time_zone = '+2:00';` on the server and check.

Comment: still nothing changed, I tried to set variable `$end_time = time()` on php and assigned it to `endtime` column instead of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` . still nothing changed

Comment: checkout this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428563/set-timezone-in-php-and-mysql